# Can Spark read data directly into a nested case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Say you have a CSV with three columns: `item`, `username`, and `userid`.  It is a fairly simple matter to use Spark's Dataset API to read this in:

```
case class Flat(item: String, username: String, userid: String)
ds = sparkSession.read.csv("path/to/data").toDF("item", "username", "userid").as[Flat]
```

Then `ds` will be of type `Dataset[Flat]`.

But suppose you would prefer that your data have the form `Dataset[Nested]` where `Nested` is given by:

```
case class User(name: String, id: String)
case class Nested(item: String, user: User)
```

One way to do it is to read the data into a `Dataset[Flat]` and then apply a `map` to transform it into a `Dataset[Nested]`, but in practice the `Flat` case class often isn't needed for anything else and it makes the code unnecessarily verbose.  Is there any way to skip the middleman and directly construct a `Dataset[Nested]`?

Comment: Did you try reading it using sparkContext instead of sqlContext, and then convert it to your nested case class using maps as you mentioned?

Comment: one of the many reasons spark sucks - it can't do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to skip the middleman and directly construct a Dataset[Nested]?

There is not - `Datasets` are match by structure and names. You cannot just have names and data has to be reshaped.

If you prefer to skip `Flat` definition just use dynamic API

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

ds.select($"item", struct($"name", $"id") as "user").as[Nested]
```

`as[Flat]` doesn't really type check so you don't loose anything.

Comment: @user8371915 - In this case, how do you access userid after mapping them as Nesting case class?

Comment: @user1384205 `.map(_.id)`.?